# MPAndroidChart: x axis labels with big text size are cut off

Tags: java, android, android-studio, charts, mpandroidchart

I have used MPAndroidChart to make a LineChart and set the x axis text size to 15. Unfortunately, the x axis labels are cut off at the top due to the big text size:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Isn't that too many labels? thats too frequent.

Comment: It's not about the value labels. It's about the x axis labels at the top!

Comment: Did you try using padding for the container the chart is in?

Comment: @SimonLiebers Yes. That did not work.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`chart.extraTopOffset` is there to save you :D